# Terminal showing ~ instead of hostname

Tags: macos, terminal

My terminal is not showing my hostname, instead it is showing the symbol ~  , It happend when I was trying to remove git(master) from my terminal.  When I tried to remove it I wrote   rm -rf .git   , after that my hostname disappeared.  I was wondering if there is anyway to recover the hostname.  I also noticed that the top of the terminal, next the expand button, theres an icon of a file with a question marked, when I click on it while holding command, a drop down menu shows with four choices but they greyed out, it shows robertomejia, Users, / , Robertos-Macbook-Pro

[image],

Comment: This needs more information, such as zsh configuration, and if you are using any config frameworks

Comment: Where would I be able to retrieve that information?

Comment: Your PS1 variable is damaged somehow, you can check it by executing `echo $PS1` - And you can fix it executing: `PS1='%n@%m %1~ %#'`

Comment: @Prado It worked for displaying my name, but it still shows the icon on the top with the questionmark